# Automate report in datewise using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas.excelwriter

I am working on an automation task and my dataframe columns are as shown below

[image: Input]

**Code:**

```
df = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1')

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Employee Name'], 
                    values='Date',fill_value=None,
                    dropna=True, margins=False)

print(df.columns.to_list())

df = df.reset_index()
```

**Calculations in Output:**

Calculation for Utilization in row:

```
Utilization = Total Hours/9 * 100
```

If Billable is 'Yes' then it calculate the Billable

Calculation for Billing in row:

```
Billable = df[Billing] * Hours/9 * 100
```

If Billable is 'No' then it calculate the Non-Billable

Calculation for Non-Billing in row:

```
Non-Billable = df[Non-Billing] * Hours/ 9* 100
```

**I want to generate a Output report as follows**

[image: Output]

Comment: Try this, first do calcs into dataframe, then do the pivot  table

Comment: @Merlin Calculations part i did,stuck with pivot table..Kindly help me